# StoreKit2 Transaction.updates does not emit transactions on subscription renew

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I'm listening for transaction updates during the whole lifetime of the app as described in the [`Transaction.updates`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/transaction/3851206-updates):

```swift
func startObservingTransactions() -> Task<Void, Error> {
    return Task.detached {
        for await result in Transaction.updates {
            print("Transaction update")

            if case .verified(let transaction) = result {
                await transaction.finish()

                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Transaction.updates` never emits transactions when a subscription renews. Also, I don't receive unfinished transactions on the app launch. Refunding a transaction, however, produces an update as expected.

I experience the same behavior on Simulator and real devices using Xcode, Sandbox, and TestFlight environments.

Is it even supposed to notify about the subscription renewals or should I just observe the transaction queue as usual?

[image]

I'm using Xcode 13.2.1, iOS 15.2.

Comment: Same here. I noticed that `Transaction.unfinished` emits the unfinished renewal transactions when the app is restarted.

Comment: I got a confirmation from the DTS that this is a known issue in iOS 15.2

Comment: It seems to still be an issue on 15.4 xcode 13.3.1.   Has anyone else found otherwise?

Comment: Looks like this is still an issue: StoreKit2, iOS 16.2, Xcode 14.2.

Comment: Still an issue: Store Kit 2, iOS 16.3, Xcode 14.2. I do not get the unfinished transactions from `Transaction.unfinished` either. Reported here as well: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/722222

Comment: Xcode 15 - RC and iOS 17 still occurring in Simulator but not on a physical device.